# how to input a text file for Ant delete task instead of a fileset

Tags: ant

Is it possible to input a text file which contains the list of files that needs to be deleted using Ant Delete task?

I know there is an option for giving a fileset inside the delete task but since I have 100's of files that need to be deleted using ant delete.

For example

```
<target name="removeJarsFromList">
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
        <fileset dir="${my_base_dir}">
          <include name="/a/file1.jar/**"/>
          <include name="/b/file2.jar/**"/>
          <include name="/somedir/file3.jar/**"/>
          <include name="/c/file4.jar/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```

Instead is there an option to have the files that needs to be deleted in a text file and give the text file as input.

myDeleteFileList.txt will have contents something like this

```
/a/file1.jar
/b/file2.jar
/somedir/file3.jar
/c/file4.jar
```

And give this file as input to the fileset ?

Answer (score 1):

there's a `includesfile` attribute for the `<delete>` task.

`includesfile:`  *The name of a file. Each line of this file is taken to be an include pattern.  All files are relative to the directory specified in **dir***. See [HERE](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html)

```
<delete dir="${base.dir}" includesfile="abc.txt"/>
```

**abc.txt:**
(**each line** is an include pattern, relative to `dir`; avoid trailing / leading *spaces*)

```
**/fileA
/x/y/fileB
z/*.java
```

---

normally, the `dir` attribute in the `<delete>` task is used to delete the entire directory, but maybe this'll work. (*i havent tried this, so*) take a **backup of your directory** or try it on a temporary directory first!